# C++ stringstreams with std::hex

Tags: c++, stringstream

I am looking into code at work. I am having following code. In following code what is the meaning of the last statement?

```
bOptMask = true;
std::string strMask;
strMask.append(optarg);
std::stringstream(strMask) >> std::hex >> iMask >> std::dec;
```

In addition to the above question: I have string input and I need to know how to convert it to an integer using C++ streams as above instead of `atoi()`.

The problem I am facing is if I give input

```
strOutput.append(optarg);
cout << "Received option for optarg is " << optarg << endl;
std::stringstream(strOutput) >> m_ivalue ;
cout << "Received option for value is " << m_ivalue << endl;
```

For the above code, if I am running with argument "a" I am having an output with first line as "a" and a second line output as 0. I am not sure why, can any one explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last statement creates a temporary stringstream and then uses it to parse the string as hexadecimal format into iMask.

There are flaws with it though, as there is no way to check that the streaming succeeded, and the last stream achieves nothing as you are dealing with a temporary.

Better would be to create the stringstream as a non-temporary, ideally using istringstream as you are only using it to parse string to int, and then checking whether the conversion succeeds.

```
std::istringstream iss( strMask );
iss >> std::hex;
if(!( iss >> iMask ))
{
 // handle the error
}
```

You only need to set the mode back to decimal if your stringstream is now about to parse a decimal integer. If it is going to parse more hex ones you can just read those in too, eg if you have a bunch of them from a file.

How you handle errors is up to you.

`std::hex` and `std::dec` are part of the `<iomanip>` part of streams that indicate the way text should be formatted. hex means "hexadecimal" and dec means "decimal". The default is to use decimal for integers and hexadecimal for pointers. For reasons unknown to me there is no such thing as a hex representation for printing float or double, i.e. no "hexadecimal point" although C99 sort-of supports it.

Answer (score 2):

The code takes the string `optarg` and, treating it as hex, converts it to an integer and stores it in iMask.

If you remove the std::hex modifier you can parse the input as decimal.  However, I usually use boost's lexical_cast for this.  For example:

```
int iMask = boost::lexical_cast< int >( strMask );
```

Comment: to make sure i under stand correctly to convert string to integer is following code is right. std::string strLevel;
strLevel.append(optarg);
std::stringstream(strLevel) >> m_iLevelSettings >> std::dec;

Comment: which does nothing except what the users code does, and you need a new object stringstream for each int you parse in a string that has a lot of them, and if it fails you get a useless exception

Comment: @CashCow It's true it does the exact same thing, but if you're just trying to parse a single number, as is the case here, I find lexical_cast<> much more readable.  If the situation doesn't warrant the exception then it may be better to use stringstream and regular error checking, I agree.

Comment: @user519882 That's correct.  Though you can also omit the >> std::dec.  That was just reseting the stream back to decimal after changing it to hex ;)

Comment: problem i am facing is if i give input strOutput.append(optarg); cout << "Received option for optarg is " << optarg << endl; std::stringstream(strOutput) >> m_iPersistSettings ; cout << "Received option for persistent is " << m_iPersistSettings << endl; For above code if i am runing with argument "a"i am having output as first line as "a" and second line output as 0. I am not sure why, can any one explain

Comment: "a" cannot be parsed as a (decimal) integer, and so the value of m_iPersistSettings will not be changed.  Are you trying to parse a hex string?

Comment: @Alex Deem I found from experience that when you do want to throw an exception, you still have to catch the boost exception to throw it again with more context. It's no use to the user to know that something somewhere failed to cast, much better they know where in the script being parsed the tyoe is not what was expected by the program, what type it wanted and what it sees.

Comment: I actually fail to see how this answers the question, as the text being read is in hexadecimal format. You cannot "remove the hex modifier".

Answer (score 1):

This code uses [manipulators](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/) to set the stream to expect integers to be read in base 16 (hexadecimal, using the digits 0123456789ABCDEF), then extracts a hexadecimal number from the string, storing it in iMask, and uses another manipulator to set the string stream back to the default of expecting integers to be written in decimal form.