# How to convert std::string representation of 64-bit address to uint64_t?

Tags: c++

I have a `std::string` representing a 64-bit memory address in little-endian, hexadecimal form. How to convert this to a `uint64_t` representation?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you get an unsigned long out of a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484140/how-do-you-get-an-unsigned-long-out-of-a-string)

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117844/c-string-streams

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "little-endian, hexadecimal"? In 16 bits, would the number `0x1234` be represented by the string `"4321"` or `"3412"` (i.e., is it byte-wise or hex-digit-wise little-endian)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdint>

int main()
{
    std::string s("0x12345");
    std::stringstream strm(s);
    std::uint64_t n;
    strm >> std::hex >> n;
    std::cout << std::hex << n << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This prints `12345`, as expected.

**Edit:** If you want to convert from little-endian to big-endian, that's possible too:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdint>

int main()
{
    std::string s("0x12345");
    std::stringstream strm(s);

    union {
        std::uint64_t n;
        std::uint8_t a[8];
    } u;

    strm >> std::hex >> u.n;
    std::reverse(u.a, u.a + 8);

    std::cout << std::hex << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(16) << u.n << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: But the string is in little-endian, hex form. For example, the memory address 0x400678 is expressed as "7806400000000000".

Comment: @RouteMapper Then you swap the bytes after the conversion.

Comment: Is there a well-known function for swapping bytes from a uint64_t type?

Comment: @RouteMapper [Here's the math for 2 bytes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916097/integer-byte-swapping-in-c), easily extensible for any number of bytes. But, if you are feeling lazy, then make an `union { uint64_t i; uint8_t a[8]; }`, then `std::reverse(u.a, u.a + 8)`.

Comment: How can you detect errors? e.g. if the string is `"ZZZ"`, this gives me 0, not a sort of error

Comment: @user529758 - You can't use a union like that in C++. It leads to [undefined behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11373203/608639). Maybe `bswap` would be a better choice.